# How to Apply a TimeDistributed Dense Layer to a tensor of shape (batch_size, 600, 105, 8) to produce output (batch_size, 600, 48)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, keras

I have a `Conv2D` layer producing a tensor of shape `(batch_size, 600, 105, 8)`. This is a batch of song spectrograms with a feature_map of 8. Now I want to apply a "Dense" layer of size 48 to each time frame (600) to produce a tensor of shape `(batch_size, 600, 48)`. The default Keras `Dense` layer doesn't seem to cut it...

Any suggestions?

This is my function

```
def build_cnn(input_shape=(None, None, 1),
          feature_map_size=8,
          num_layers=5,
          kernerl_size=(5, 5),
          dropout=0.2,
          pool_size=(2, 2),
          epochs=100,
          lr=0.001,
          momentum=0.9,
          verbose=False):

    model = Sequential()

    # Add the convolutional layers
    for _ in range(num_layers):     
        # Conv layer
        model.add(Conv2D(
            feature_map_size,
            kernerl_size,
            input_shape=input_shape,
            padding='same',
            activation='elu')
        )
        # Dropout layer
        # model.add(Dropout(dropout))

    # Dense layer
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(48, activation='elu')))
```

Comment: If time trame is 600, what is 105?

Comment: @DanielMöller Number of bins in a Logarithmically compressed Mel-Scale Magnitude Spectrogram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most basic and insensitive way of doing it, is reshaping the data:

```
#after the convolutions:

model.add(Reshape((600,105*8)))
model.add(Dense(48,...))
```

But this may not be the best choice. Unfortunately I don't understand those spectograms very well so suggest other approaches. But this one basically throws all bins and features in a Dense layer, and they will be mixed together.

---

In case reshaping with `-1` fails

There is a possibility of handling with unknown shapes inside lambda layers with backend functions. But this only works with tensorflow as backend. Theano doesn't like the idea. I gave up theano because of this.

```
#valid in tensorflow only
import keras.backend as K

def reshape(x):
    shp = K.shape(x)
    shp = K.concatenate([shp[:2],shp[2:3]*shp[3:]])
    return K.reshape(x,shp)

model.add(Lambda(reshape))
```

Comment: If the first dimension (600) is variable, can I say

#after the convolutions:

`model.add(Reshape((-1,105*8)))` ?

Comment: Hmm, not sure, internally, there will be two `-1` values (one for the batch dimension and the other as input). You can try it, but in case it doesn't work, there is a possibility that I'll put in my answer.

Comment: Updated the answer.